# wordpress site error after using virus scanner from Cpanel

Tags: wordpress, header, cpanel, fatal-error

I scanned my website virus from cpanel virus scanner and its scanned some viruses is /logs folder and some in /mail/... folders some mails
I deleted those destroy all those mails and quarantined one file from /logs follder after that my site is not accessing 
here is the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ts_theme_favicon() in /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-content/themes/gon/header.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(688): require_once() #1 /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(647): load_template('/home/worldlink/...', true) #2 /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php(41): locate_template(Array, true) #3 /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-content/themes/gon/page.php(3): get_header('') #4 /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74): include('/home/worldlink/...') #5 /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/worldlink/...') #6 /home/worldlink/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/worldlink/...') #7 {main} thrown in /home/worldlink/public_html/wp-content/themes/gon/header.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see errors with the WordPress core, such as:

```
/home/worldlink/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php
```

it's time to reinstall WordPress. It's likely there is malicious code in the core files they was referencing one of the files you deleted, and that's why you're suddenly getting errors.

I've found [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) to be a brilliant plugin for scanning all the files that make up your website (core, theme and plugins) and identifying exactly which files have been compromised.

In the error you reported, your theme is giving errors as well:

```
/home/worldlink/public_html/wp-content/themes/gon/header.php
```

Try switching to another theme and seeing if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yeah re installing the theme solved the issue.
Anyway theme is nulled I think so thats why this error occured after virus scanning. Is there any issue with that theme. How to resolve those virus without effecting the theme.